# Invoke docker from python

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I am very new to docker so I am highly confused.

```
    a= 'o1 & o2 | -o3'
    p=subprocess.Popen("docker run -ti ajaveeda/satisker:first /data/satisolve '{} ".format(a + " ' "),shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=sys.stderr)
    output, err = p.communicate()
    output = output.decode('utf-8')
    print(output)
```

I installed a docker toolbox to my Windows 10 computer. When I type `"docker run -ti ajaveeda/satisker:first /data/satisolve "o1 & o2 | -o3" "`, docker gives me 
"SATISFIABLE
 Solution:
o1  =  True,
o2  =  False,
o3  =  False" as an output. By using a code piece given above, I want to invoke docker from a python code and print out the output. However, when I use the code piece, I get

> io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

error. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you run subprocess using python it creates a child process and delivers the command to it. So, when you run docker run command it creates an conatiner instance and lets you run a command inside the container.
When you run **docker run**, it creates a conatiner and remains inside the conatiner. 
**docker run --rm** inside your python code
This will exit from the conatiner once the command is executed.
Please check the quotes formatting once **subprocess.Popen()**